# What does maxDiscardedFactor do in ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

The documentation for `PropertyCheckConfiguration` is basically empty and in particular it is not documented what the `maxDiscardedFactor` setting does, and in particular, how it is different from `PropertyCheckConfig`'s `maxDiscarded` setting (as the latter has been deprecated). Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxDiscardedFactor` in ScalaTest is the same of [`maxDiscardedRatio`](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/0f46e169153a4677fa30bf51e297ecbb580b14bd/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Test.scala#L72) of ScalaCheck: it represents the maximum allowed ratio between discarded and passed property evaluations.

Instead, the deprecated `maxDiscarded` represents an absolute number of the maximum discarded tests allowed per property.

According to [this ScalaTest issue](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/pull/428), `maxDiscarded` has been deprecated in favor of `maxDiscardedFactor`, while in the ScalaCheck project the `maxDiscarded` property has been completely removed [(see here)](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/11).

Comment: They clearly aren't the same, as `maxDiscardedFactor` is a double and the other is an int. `maxDiscardedFactor` seems like it is some kind of ratio (but a ratio between what?), whereas `maxDiscarded` was just an integer indicating the maximum number of allowable discarded trials.

Comment: @ubadub you're right, hope my edit here helps in figuring out what they mean.